# ¿Cómo valido un input sin usar required?

Tags: html, formularios, required

El tema es que tengo un `textarea` que está **requerido**, pero lo que quiero es que si el usuario envia el formulario sin escribir nada en el textarea, **no**  **aparezca** el mensaje de `Esta requerido` pero si mantenga la validación de no dejar pasar los datos al servidor y le señale al usuario el input que no pasa la validación por estar vacio.

La imagen siguiente muestra un resumen de lo que quiero ocultar:

[image: Esto es lo que quiero ocultar]

Comment: Por favor la próxima vez adjunta algo de código así sea de ejemplo. De esa forma estimulas a los lectores (nosotros) a colaborarte mejor. Un Saludo

Comment: Vale, lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En las partes de tu formulario donde tengas la etiqueta "required" bórralas:

Ejemplo:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Para validar el campo vacío puedes usar javascript puro (https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_js):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

O plugins de validación: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

De preferencia implementa la validación tanto en servidor como en el 
cliente.

La validación a nivel cliente es para que tu usuario no pierda tiempo esperando a que el servidor le diga que llene el campo vacío.

La de nivel servidor te sirve en caso que la validación a nivel cliente falle y que el usuario no ponga datos basura o quiera perjudicar tu servidor.

Comment: Lo que pido simplemente es que si el textarea esté vacio y el usuario da a submit no le salga ningun aviso ni nada, y no envie el formulario

Comment: Simplemente como te comenté, quita los  "required" de tu formulario. En el ejemplo de javascript que puse solo cometa el "alert" y listo.

Comment: Ok, amigo ya lo solucione, escribí esto:
    
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        if( ! ("autofocus" in document.createElement( "input" ) ) )
 {
 document.getElementById( "input" ).focus();
 }
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

Pero, como hago para volver a tener seleccionada el textarea, hice focus y no funcionó

Comment: Es justo como te dice @PAGANA. Es la respuesta exacta a tu pregunta, ya el comentario que haces arriba es otra pregunta totalmente diferente o al menos podrías colocar un código de ejemplo con el que estes probando y así nosotros te ayudamos a corregir los errores o a mejorarlos. Un Saludo

Comment: @Huskie yo pedia que no apareciese nada, y su respuesta me hace aparecer un alert de javascript, pero gracias a su respuesta he cambiado la parte de alert y he obtenido lo que pedía

Answer (score 2):

Los campos de un formulario tiene eventos específicos, uno de ellos es [`onInvalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/invalid) que se lanza antes de que el formulario se envíe si el campo es incorrecto (no cumple con las condiciones para ser enviado).

Entonces, puedes tener tus campos con `required` y poner un controlador del evento `invalid` que haga un [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para evitar que se muestre el mensaje de error, y el formulario tampoco se enviará.

Por ejemplo, este formulario tiene un campo requerido. Si no se introduce, debería salir el mensaje de error que quieres evitar, pero antes de que eso ocurra, lo prevenimos en el controlador del evento `invalid`:

```js
var nombre = document.querySelector("[name=Nombre]");

nombre.addEventListener("invalid", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre (Requerido)" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```